# Difference between Behat and selenium webdriver automation tool

Tags: selenium, webdriver, behat

Major difference between "Behat" and "Selenium Webdriver" automation tool

Comment: One starts with "B", the other with "S".

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Comment: Could you please share with me link of the docs?

Comment: Just click on the specific tag and you will see on the top of the page a description with some links.

Answer (score 0):

Behat is a cucumber-based BDD automation framework that utilises a human readable front end (.feature files) to better describe what your tests are doing, to a target audience (usually, non-technical business people).

Selenium Webdriver is an automation library used for driving web automation. It interacts with browsers and elements within the browser.